# Weird subtraction result in golang

Tags: go, floating-point, precision

code:

```
func main() {
    var idle float64 = 1.8483711496702958e+18
    busy := float64(100.0) - idle
    sum := idle + busy
    fmt.Printf("idle: %f\n", idle)
    fmt.Printf("busy: %f\n", busy)
    fmt.Printf("sum: %f\n", sum)
}
```

result:

```
idle: 1848371149670295808.000000
busy: -1848371149670295808.000000
sum: 0.000000
```

I would ask why `busy` + `idle` = 0.000?

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/WmtK9AuN_yt

Comment: I don't know what you expect. `idle` and `busy` are same values, except one is signed. If you add them, the result should be `0`, which it tells correctly

Comment: Notice that `busy=100-idle`, so I expect that `busy+idle`  shoule be 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`idle` compared to `busy` is several orders of magnitude bigger, the difference is like 10^16 times! That's bigger than the precision of floating point numbers which is defined by [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Adding `100` to `-idle` won't change it "much".

If you decrease `idle`, you get what you expect:

```
var idle float64 = 1.8483711496702958e+15
```

With this change, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qm1Zx5vn2y2)):

```
idle: 1848371149670295.750000
busy: -1848371149670195.750000
sum: 100.000000
```

Floating point numbers only store the most significant bits of a number. If `idle` is around 10^18, adding 100 to it would only change bits that are not represented precisely (or at all). If you decrease `idle` to like 10^15 or lower, then adding 100 will change bits that are still represented, and you'll see the expected result.